# How to get substring using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to get a couple values out of a url using regular expression. Since i am not familiar i was hoping someone could guide me .

I have a url i am trying to manipulate looks like this .

```
var urlString = "/myMessages/v2/messages/I15/parts/0"
```

The values i am trying to get are I15 and 0 . 
These values could be anything but the format of urlString would remain the same. What is the best and most efficient way to go about obtaining these values?

Comment: You don't even need regex, you can use `split`

Comment: `urlString.split('/')[4]` and `urlString.split('/')[6]`

Comment: @anubhava `var urlString = "/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something this simple, a straightforward solution is to use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead:

```
var urlString = "/myMessages/v2/messages/I15/parts/0";
var parts = urlString.split('/');
var value1 = parts[4]; // "I15"
var value2 = parts[6]; // "0"
```

This will work just fine as long as you know exactly how many `/` characters will appear before the parts you're interested in.

If you also know that the URL will always begin with `"/myMessages/v2/messages/"`, you might be able to make this a bit more efficient:

```
var urlString = "/myMessages/v2/messages/I15/parts/0";
var substring = urlString.substr(24), 
    i = substring.indexOf('/'),
    j = substring.indexOf('/', i);
var value1 = substring.substr(0, i);  // "I15"
var value2 = substring.substr(j + 1); // "0"
```

However, efficiency really shouldn't be your first priority. You should optimize for readability.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a slightly more robust solution than what's been proposed so far:

```
var urlString = "<url string coming in some undetermined order>";
var parts = urlString.split('/');
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
  map[parts[i]] = parts[i+1];
}
```

This way your values are now stored along with the keys to access them, which you can set in any way you want.

So say your URL is `/myMessages/v2/partnum/2/messages/I18/thing/splund/foo/bar` and you want the values of `partnum`, `thing`, and `foo`, but you don't necessarily know that they'll be in the order I just put up in that url.  Using the method I suggested, you can simply access their values using:

```
var partnum = map['partnum'] // '2'
var thing = map['thing']     // 'splund'
var foo = map['foo']         // 'bar'
```

Comment: i had the same idea but you loop is much smarter than mine. :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would use regex for this. I would create a custom function to handle urls of this type:

```
function handleUrlTokens(url){
  var parts = url.split('/').filter(function(o){return o!==''})
  var params = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i+=2) {
    param[parts[i]] = parts[i+1];
  }
  return params;
}
handleUrlTokens("/myMessages/v2/messages/I15/parts/0") //Object {myMessages: "v2", messages: "I15", parts: "0"}
```

This would then be able to handle many different types of url, as long as the convention is /key/value/key/value.

Edited because revenProdigalKnight's loop was better than mine.

Comment: +1 for crediting me with a better loop, though yours would have worked fine.

Comment: Yours is definitely more concise though!

Answer (score 0):

`\/messages\/([^\/]+)\/parts\/(.*)`

Then use the first and second matched groups.

Comment: Your slashes need to be escaped if used for a regex match... `urlString.match(/\/messages\/([^/]+)\/parts\/(.*)/)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = urlString.split('/')[4];
var second = urlString.split('/')[6];
```

Note that this will not work if the order is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlString = "/myMessages/v2/messages/I15/parts/0"
var reqArray = urlString.split('/');

console.log(reqArray[4],reqArray[6]);
```

This is the better way, when compared to regular expression.

It works fine for me!!